# Python: compose a search results URL

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I would like to compose a form results URL whereas certain parts can be programatically changed. I've read similar questions were `requests` `urljoin()` is used but it can take only two parameters. Is there anything more appropriate for this scenario?

This is the base

```
https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?func=TT&ReservationType=npgres.exe%3FPM%3DBO&Leg1i=
```

This part is the route which will need to change

```
BEV&Leg1ii=PRJ
```

This is the date  which will need to change

```
&Leg1Date=28%2F02%2F2019
```

This part will not need changing

```
&TotalPassengers=1&TotalPassengersHuman=1&TotalPassengersAcce=0&TotalVehicles=0
```

Comment: "can take only two parameters"   Uh, what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`urllib.parse.urlencode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode), it takes a mapping or two-element tuple sequence and produces a properly-encoded query string:

```
import urllib.parse

params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
    "Leg1ii": "PRJ",
    "Leg1Date": "28/02/2019",
    "TotalPassengers": "1",
    "TotalPassengersHuman": "1",
    "TotalPassengersAcce": "0",
    "TotalVehicles": "0",
})

print(f"https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?{params}")
```

Result:

```
https://navlib.forth-crs.gr/italian_b2c/npgres.exe?Leg1ii=PRJ&Leg1Date=28%2F02%2F2019&TotalPassengers=1&TotalPassengersHuman=1&TotalPassengersAcce=0&TotalVehicles=0
```